# Get the image sizes after being uploaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm working on a tool which allows users to upload an image asynchronously using ajax. Then the user can resize his image with a slider from jQuery UI.
However I'm having some troubles with the variables values which get the image size for resizing the image, because when the page is loaded there is no image, so the variables are set to zero.

I would like to find a way to refresh *orginalWidth* and *orginalHeight* as soon as an image is uploaded.

Here is the code:

```
//Upload the image with AJAX

$('#uploadForm').on('change', (function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
        $("#image").attr('src',data);
        },
        error: function() 
        {
        }           
   });
}));

    //Resize slider with jQuery UI
    
        
    var orginalWidth  = $("#image").width();
    var orginalHeight = $("#image").height();
        
    $("#infoSlider").text(orginalWidth + ', ' + orginalHeight + ', 100%');

    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: -50,
        max: 50,
        step: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
        
        var fraction = (1 + ui.value / 100),
        newWidth = orginalWidth * fraction,
        newHeight = orginalHeight * fraction;

            $("#infoSlider").text(newWidth + ', ' + newHeight + ', ' + Math.floor(fraction * 100) + '%');

            $("#image").width(newWidth);
        }
    });
```

Edit :

So @FlashThunder told me to use PHP to get the image size. However my PHP code doesn't work (JS Variables "Undefined").

PHP Code :

```
//Check if the file is well uploaded
if($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0) { echo 'Error during uploading, try again'; }

//We won't use $_FILES['file']['type'] to check the file extension for security purpose

//Set up valid image extensions
$extsAllowed = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' );

//Extract extension from uploaded file
    //substr return ".jpg"
    //Strrchr return "jpg"
    
$extUpload = strtolower( substr( strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'], '.') ,1) ) ;

//Check if the uploaded file extension is allowed

if (in_array($extUpload, $extsAllowed) ) { 

    //Upload the file on the server

    $name = "img/{$_FILES['file']['name']}";
    $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $name);


    if($result){
        //echo "$name";
        
        //Save the image size
        //$filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($name);
        $data = array('src' => $name, 'width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
        echo json_encode($data);
        
    }
    
} else { echo 'File is not valid. Please try again'; }
```

JS code :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            //data:  new FormData(this),
            data : 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#image").attr('src', data.src);
                var orginalWidth  = data.width;
                var orginalHeight = data.height;
                alert(orginalWidth);
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use your PHP upload script to do this. It could return object describing image size, and in Ajax success function it would get the values.

For example PHP could contain something like this:

```
$data = array('src' => $src,'width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
echo json_encode($data);
```

and in JS:

```
...
dataType: 'json',
...
success: function(data){
   $("#image").attr('src',data.src);
   console.log(data.height);
   console.log(data.width);
}
```

Exactly something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "upload.php",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   dataType : 'json',
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData:false,
   success: function(data){
       $("#image").attr('src',data.src);
       console.log(data.height);
       console.log(data.width);
   },         
});
```

Image size can be obtained by PHP function [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/getimagesize).

Comment: I would like to avoid PHP for this one, but if I don't any choice I'll use it.

Comment: You could use `load` function, to get an image size after it loads in browser, but it doesn't always work. Had alot of problems with it, especially when image is not new and it is in cache.

Comment: Ok, but my "data" is set for a formData. How can I send back two more value using php?

Comment: @casusbelli: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: I did as you told me. But it doesn't work. I edit my first message. If you can throw an eye on it I would be so graceful.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you changed `data` option in ajax request... and you should add `dataType : 'json'` - two different options... `data` is what is being sent to server by `POST` method... and `dataType` is what is being expected in result returned by server. Edited answer to show full JS function.

Comment: it works ! Thank you so much FlashThunder. Sorry for my poor skill with JS, I'm really new with it. I'll credit you on my website! thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must take the image size to what the image is loaded

```
success: function(data){
    $("#image").one('load',function() {
        var orginalWidth  = $("#image").width();
        var orginalHeight = $("#image").height();
    }).attr('src',data);
},
```

[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)